# Zuul routes priority higher than Spring Controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

I have controller in my api gateway service:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
```

And I have the same endpoint in one of my routes.

When I call /test, my request get routed, how can I increase priority of Spring Controllers over zuul routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use add a route to your controller using **forward** in front of your path, for example:

```
 zuul:
  routes:
    controller:
      path: /test
      url: forward:/test
    other:
      ...
```

and place it before your other route definition, in case of YAML file it will preserve an order.

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_strangulation_patterns_and_local_forwards

I haven't tested above example, but I use a similar solution and it works fine.

Comment: If I don't have endpoint in my gateway I want it to be routed, but it get cycled with this config.

Comment: Is there any difference between the paths of these two endpoints internal and external one? Or both are just `/test` and you always want to be directed to the internal one?

Comment: Both just /test, I want to use internal one instead of external, like it's working by default

Comment: I've updated an example, I think it should be enough to put `forward:/test` route in front of the external ones. But still, the basic idea is to use `forward` keyword to route the traffic to controllers defined inside the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a BeanPostProcessor to reduce the order of ZuulHandlerMapping. Default is -200

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ZuulBeanPostProcessor postBean() {
        return new ZuulBeanPostProcessor();
    }

 
    public static class ZuulBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

        @Override
        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            return bean;
        }

        @Override
        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
            if (bean instanceof ZuulHandlerMapping) {
                ((ZuulHandlerMapping) bean).setOrder(10);
            }
            return bean;
        }
    }
}
```